# Are there Shankaracharyas outside of Adi-Shankara's direct lineage?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

I even read online somewhere (don't have the link handy, will dig it out) that there are many shankaracharyas who basically claimed links one of the 4 seats set up by Adi-Shankara.

Who might they be?

Comment: No they cant be called shankarachaya

Comment: May be Kanchi mutt, it is controversial. They have Shankaracharya link tracing to 500BC where as Sringeri mutt dates Adi shankaracharya 788AD..

Comment: @RaRe I had already removed Kanchi from the scope by saying 4 seats in the question.